# EF Core 7 migration Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

Using VS22 as IDE, EF Core(Ver. 7.0.5) as an ORM and LocalDB  with a code first approach, when trying to create a migration via:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Test
```

I get the following output:

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Initialize(ColumnOperation columnOperation, IColumn column, RelationalTypeMapping typeMapping, Boolean isNullable, IEnumerable`1 migrationsAnnotations, Boolean inline)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.InitializeColumnHelper(ColumnOperation columnOperation, IColumn column, Boolean inline)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Add(IColumn target, DiffContext diffContext, Boolean inline)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.CastIterator[TResult](IEnumerable source)+MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Add(ITable target, DiffContext diffContext)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.DiffCollection[T](IEnumerable`1 sources, IEnumerable`1 targets, DiffContext diffContext, Func`4 diff, Func`3 add, Func`3 remove, Func`4[] predicates)+MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ConcatIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.Sort(IEnumerable`1 operations, DiffContext diffContext)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationsModelDiffer.GetDifferences(IRelationalModel source, IRelationalModel target)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Design.MigrationsScaffolder.ScaffoldMigration(String migrationName, String rootNamespace, String subNamespace, String language)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The general concept of the project is to create an application to facilitate hobby leagues for a video game. Maybe someone can help me out, because I can't seem to find why that issue pops up. I know there is an object refence not set to an object but I can't for the life of me find where.
This is my first time really working with EF Core and at this point I'd be fine creating this DB and the EF Core mapping by hand, so if there is good documentation or a tutorial for that I'd be thankful for a link or something.

This is my DBContext

```
using E_Sporg.Domain.DomainModel;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions;


namespace E_Sporg.Persistenc
{
    public class CDbContext : DbContext
    {
        #region fields
        public DbSet<Player> players => Set<Player>();
        public DbSet<Team> teams => Set<Team>();
        public DbSet<League> leagues => Set<League>();
        public DbSet<Matches> matches => Set<Matches>();
        public DbSet<MatchStatsLeague> matchstatsleague => Set<MatchStatsLeague>();
        #endregion

        #region ctor
        public CDbContext(DbContextOptions<CDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
        #endregion

        #region methods
        public bool SaveAllChanges()
        {
            var records = SaveChanges();
            return records > 0;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

And these are the classes that I'm trying to work into the database:
Players that are part of the League

```
namespace E_Sporg.Domain.DomainModel
{
    public class Player
    {
        #region properties
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
        public string PlayerName { get; set; }  = string.Empty;
        public Team _team { get; set; } = default!;
        public Guid TeamId { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
        #endregion

        #region ctor
        public Player(): base() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); }
        #endregion

        #region methods
        public Player Set(Guid id, string playerName, Team _team)
        {
            Id = (id == Guid.Empty) ? Guid.NewGuid() : id;
            PlayerName = playerName;
            TeamId = _team.Id;
            return this;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

The Teams participating

```
namespace E_Sporg.Domain.DomainModel
{
    public class Team 
    {
        #region properties
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
        public string _teamName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [NotMapped] public Dictionary<Guid, Player> _player { get; set; } = default!;
        //public League _league { get; set; }
        public Guid LeagueId { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
        #endregion

        #region ctor
        public Team(): base() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); }
        #endregion

        #region methods
        public Team Set(Guid id, string teamName, Guid leagueid)
        {
            Id = (id == Guid.Empty) ? Guid.NewGuid() : id;
            _teamName = teamName;
            LeagueId = leagueid;
            return this;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

The Leagues that contain the teams

```
namespace E_Sporg.Domain.DomainModel
{
    public class League
    {
        #region properties
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
        public string LeagueName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        [NotMapped] public Dictionary<Guid, Team> _teams { get; set; } = default!;
        [NotMapped] public Dictionary<Guid, Matches> _matches { get; set; } = default!;
        #endregion

        #region ctor
        public League() : base() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); }
        #endregion

        #region methods
        public League Set(Guid id, string leagueName)
        {
            Id = (id == Guid.Empty) ? Guid.NewGuid() : id;
            LeagueName = leagueName;
            return this;
        }

        public void AddTeam(Team team)
        {
            if (!_teams.ContainsKey(team.Id))
            {
                _teams.Add(team.Id, team);
                return;
            }
            else return;
        }

        public void RemoveTeam(Team team)
        {
            if (_teams.ContainsKey(team.Id))
            {
                _teams.Remove(team.Id);
                return;
            }
            else return;
        }

        public void AddMatch(Matches match)
        {
            if (!_matches.ContainsKey(match.Id))
            {
                _matches.Add(match.Id, match);
                return;
            }
            else return;
        }

        public void RemoveMatch(Guid matchId)
        {
            if (_matches.ContainsKey(matchId))
            {
                _matches.Remove(matchId);
                return;
            }
            else return;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Matches between different Teams

```
namespace E_Sporg.Domain.DomainModel
{
    public class Matches
    {
        #region properties
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
        public Team TeamBlue { get; set; } = default!;
        public Guid TeamBlueID { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
        public Team TeamRed { get; set; } = default!;
        public Guid TeamRedID { get; set; } =Guid.Empty;
        [NotMapped] public Dictionary<Guid, object[]> TeamBlueStats { get; set; } = default!;
        [NotMapped] public Dictionary<Guid, object[]> TeamRedStats { get; set; } = default!;
        #endregion

        #region ctor
        public Matches(): base() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); }
        #endregion

        #region methods
        public Matches Set(Guid id, Team _teamBlue, Team _teamRed)
        {
            Id = (id ==  Guid.Empty) ? Guid.NewGuid() : id;
            TeamBlue = _teamBlue;
            TeamBlueID = TeamBlue.Id;
            TeamRed = _teamRed;
            TeamRedID = TeamRed.Id;
            return this;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

And MatchStats these are the stats each of the players accumulate in a match with the references to the league, match and player

```
namespace E_Sporg.Domain.DomainModel
{
    public class MatchStatsLeague
    {
        #region properties
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
        public Guid LeagueId { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
        public Guid MatchId { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
        public Guid PlayerId { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
        //stats
        public string Champion { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public Role Role { get; set; }
        public int Kills { get; set; } = int.MinValue;
        public int Deaths { get; set; } = int.MinValue;
        public int Assists { get; set; } = int.MinValue;
        public int DmgPerMin { get; set; } = int.MinValue;
        public int CSPerMin { get; set; } = int.MinValue;
        public int GoldPerMin { get; set; } = int.MinValue;
        #endregion

        #region ctor
        public MatchStatsLeague() : base() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); }
        #endregion

        public MatchStatsLeague Set(Guid _leagueId, Guid _matchId, Guid _playerId, object[] _playerStats)
        {
            
            LeagueId = _leagueId;
            MatchId = _matchId;
            PlayerId = _playerId;
           
            Champion = (string)_playerStats[0];
            Role = (Role)_playerStats[1];
            Kills = (int)_playerStats[2];
            Deaths = (int)_playerStats[3];
            Assists = (int)_playerStats[4];
            DmgPerMin = (int)_playerStats[5];
            CSPerMin = (int)_playerStats[6];
            GoldPerMin = (int)_playerStats[7];
            return this;
        }
        
    }
}
```

I'd be thankful for any tips and pointers and thanks for taking the time to read all of this

Comment: [Design-time DbContext Creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I'm guessing you are referring to [this part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory) of the article in particular? If not I might need some more context.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a migration that changed some fields from DateTime (datetime2) to DateTimeOffset (datetimeoffset). All migrations after that failed. Might be a bug in the EF Core tools.